# how to prove the set of constructible numbers is countable?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory

I know what is constructible numbers and I know to how to prove a set is countable by bijection but I don't know how to prove the set of constructible numbers is countable.

Comment: Can you show that all constructible numbers are algebraic? How many algebraic numbers are there?

Comment: don‘t get why is it related to algebraic

Comment: The rationals are constructible and algebraic. If $a$ and $b$ are algebraic, how about, $a+b$, $ab$, $\sqrt{a}$, etc.?

Comment: Just how many constructions are there?

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

develop this idea:

the constructible numbers are a subset of the algebraic numbers and this is a countable set because the algebric numbers are roots of a polynomial and the set of polynomials is countable and any polynomial has a finite number of roots.

Comment: get it, thx a lot